# STM32 Implementing UART Cplt Callback Stops Transmission in Int or DMA Mode

Tags: stm32, uart

I have a project using the STM32L010F4 that needs to receive six bytes of data from the UART. If I build a sample project using STMCubeMX with interrupt receive mode, all works fine: the UART IRQ handler fires, and I get my six bytes.

I then decided I wanted to try and use the DMA. I started adding the DMA init code (keeping in mind from old posts the DMA init needs to take place BEFORE the UART init). I can still use the HAL_UART_Receive_IT function and everything is still good.

However, as soon as I try to implement my own HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback, the IRQ no longer fires and I get no data. My understanding is the existing HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback implemented in the HAL is defined as weak, so my callback should override it. However, even if I comment out the existing weak HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback, the UART IRQ STILL does not fire and I get no data.

What am I doing wrong?

```
  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and 
 the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();

  uint8_t Result = 0;
  uint8_t RX_Data[6] = {0};

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
      Result = HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, RX_Data, 6 );
      HAL_Delay(100);

      if (Result == HAL_OK)
      {
          HAL_Delay(20);
      }

   }
}

void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
  HAL_Delay(20);
}

* @brief USART2 Initialization Function
* @param None
* @retval None
*/
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void)
{
  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 1 */
  huart2.Instance = USART2;
  huart2.Init.BaudRate = 57600;
  huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  huart2.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  huart2.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * Enable DMA controller clock
  */
static void MX_DMA_Init(void)
{

  /* DMA controller clock enable */
  __HAL_RCC_DMA1_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* DMA interrupt init */
  /* DMA1_Channel2_3_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel2_3_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel2_3_IRQn);
}

void HAL_UART_MspInit(UART_HandleTypeDef* huart)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
  if(huart->Instance==USART2)
  {
    /* Peripheral clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_USART2_CLK_ENABLE();

    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
    /**USART2 GPIO Configuration
    PA0-CK_IN     ------> USART2_RX
    PA2     ------> USART2_TX
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF0_USART2;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_2;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF4_USART2;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    /* USART2 DMA Init */
    /* USART2_RX Init */
    hdma_usart2_rx.Instance = DMA1_Channel3;
    hdma_usart2_rx.Init.Request = DMA_REQUEST_4;
    hdma_usart2_rx.Init.Direction = DMA_PERIPH_TO_MEMORY;
    hdma_usart2_rx.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
    hdma_usart2_rx.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
    hdma_usart2_rx.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_usart2_rx.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_usart2_rx.Init.Mode = DMA_NORMAL;
    hdma_usart2_rx.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_LOW;
    if (HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_usart2_rx) != HAL_OK)
    {
      Error_Handler();
    }

    __HAL_LINKDMA(huart,hdmarx,hdma_usart2_rx);

    /* USART2_TX Init */
    hdma_usart2_tx.Instance = DMA1_Channel2;
    hdma_usart2_tx.Init.Request = DMA_REQUEST_4;
    hdma_usart2_tx.Init.Direction = DMA_MEMORY_TO_PERIPH;
    hdma_usart2_tx.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
    hdma_usart2_tx.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
    hdma_usart2_tx.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_usart2_tx.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_usart2_tx.Init.Mode = DMA_NORMAL;
    hdma_usart2_tx.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_LOW;
    if (HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_usart2_tx) != HAL_OK)
    {
      Error_Handler();
    }

    __HAL_LINKDMA(huart,hdmatx,hdma_usart2_tx);

    /* USART2 interrupt Init */
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(USART2_IRQn, 0, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART2_IRQn);
  }
}
```

Comment: EDIT: It appears it's th HAL_Delay inside my callback function. Not sure why that's causing it to stop transmitting. I must be creating a race condition I am not immediately seeing.

Comment: It's a bad idea to call `HAL_Delay()` inside an ISR. If the sysTick interrupt is lower priority than your DMA interrupt, then it will not run, and your delay will never complete.

Comment: @pmacfarlane Yeah, I think that's exactly what was happening. I only stuck it there to have a spot for a break point.